# How can I disable a form with javascript onchange function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eclipse, forms, disabled-input

I'm trying to disable a form in a JSP just when two conditions become true. I've tried a var variable set false so when my if-else condition becomes true it becomes true. But it is not working.

Here is my code. (not sure if it can help but I'm using eclipse)

```
var disabled=false;
```

then I've created the function

```
function isDisable(){
    if($("#idCost").val() == 1 && $("#IdBasket").val() == "3"){
        disabled=true;
    }
}
```

and then set in the form field

```
< disabled="false"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Did my answer help at all?

Comment: Hi Kevin! I didnt think about that, because both of them are option value. However how can i make both number or string?

Comment: It would be easier if you post your entire file contents. I'm assuming you're using jQuery, but I'm not sure if your code is getting called. Do you know how to add a breakpoint to the JavaScript in the browser? If so, then add one if your function. If the code doesn't hit the breakpoint, then it's not being executed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is in JavaScript and not Java, even though you say you are writing a JSP.

Your JS code compare one return to a Number (val() == 1) and another to a String val() == "3". Did you try making them both the same? If .val() is returning strings, then they should both compare to strings. If .val() is returning numbers, then they should both compare to numbers.